# How to fetch Youtube public channel stats without authentication

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to fetch metrics like views, likes, dislikes for videos in some popular public Youtube channels and also subscription information of the Channelsa on a daily basis. Also, country wise stats and gender wise stats for the channels required. But, Youtube Reporting API always prompts authentication. Is there any way to fetch those metrics for public Youtube channels without user authentication?(https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports - need to use this API). Your suggestions will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

For some of read-only requests you can just use access token without need to authorize. Check the documentation. Each request's documentation tells if authorization is needed.

Answer (score 0):

The API you linked to is part of the "[YouTube Analytics and Reporting APIs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/)", which is split up in these very two pieces - analytics and reporting. I don't see why you need to use this exact API, but I can tell you that you won't succeed with it. This API is intended for channel owners and network owners to get information about **their own channels**. You absolutely **have** to authenticate via OAuth in order to use it, there is no way around this.

In order to get video and channel metrics, you can consult the [YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started). Here, an API key from the [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com) will let you fetch any public data without further authentication. But it will not provide you with data records in specific periods of time, it always returns the current values of the requested properties.

In other words: what you are asking is, as far as I know, impossible to achieve with any official YouTube API.

A workaround for your problem would be to fetch the desired properties via the Data API on a, say, daily basis and compare their values to the previous day's values and calculate the delta.